# Laravel: query many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4, many-to-many

I have a `User` model which `belongsToMany()` `Conferences`. `Conferences` `hasMany` `Users`, also a m:m relationship.
I am working on a `link()` method in my `ConferencesController`, but I'm not sure how to go about.

I collect the given `Conference` by `id`, and the `Auth::check`-ed `User`. How do I add the conference and user into the `pivot table`?

Answer (score 1):

create a pivot table

```
//conference_user
Schema::create('conference_user', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('conference_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('conference_id')->references('id')->on('conferences');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

now in User model, add this method

```
public function conferences()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Conference','conference_user');
}
```

and in Conference model, add this method

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','conference_user');
}
```

now in your controller, you can use something like this

```
$conferences=$user->conferences;
```

or

```
$users=$conference->users;
```